# runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy a containerized webapp on Openshift by a helm chart. When I deploy the app I get the following error in the pod logs -

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                   From               Message

  Normal   Pulled          14m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "<private-gitlab-registry-docker-image>:latest" in 3.787555091s
  Warning  Failed          14m                   kubelet            Error: container create failed: time="2022-11-11T13:51:47Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: \"python3 src/myapp.py\": stat python3 src/myapp.py: no such file or directory"
```

Here is the dockerfile -

```
FROM <private-gitlab-registry-centos-image>

ADD files/etc/yum.repos.d/* /etc/yum.repos.d/

RUN yum update -y

WORKDIR /app

RUN yum install -y python-keystoneclient python3-flask python3-keystoneauth1 python3-redis python3-werkzeug python3-pip python3-keystoneclient
RUN pip install flask-caching

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

CMD [ "src/myapp.py" ]
```

When I manually try to run this docker image, it works just fine. But when I deploy it on Kubernetes, kubelet throws the above error.

Here is my deployment.yaml -

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment                 # Type of Kubernetes resource
metadata:
  name: myapp             # Unique name of the Kubernetes resource
spec:
  replicas: 1                    # Number of pods to run at any given time
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp          # This deployment applies to any Pods matching the specified label
  template:                      # This deployment will create a set of pods using the configurations in this template
    metadata:
      labels:                    # The labels that will be applied to all of the pods in this deployment
        app: myapp 
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.imagePullPolicy }}
          {{- include "myapp.command" . | nindent 8 }}
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080  # Should match the port number that the Go application listens on    
        env:                     # Environment variables passed to the container
          - name: REDIS_HOST
            value: redis-master
          - name: REDIS_PORT
            value: "6379"
```

And values.yaml -

```
image:
  repository: gitlab-registry.cern.ch/batch-team/hepspec-query/hepspec-query
  tag: latest
  imagePullSecret: {}
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  command: [ "python3" , "src/hepspecapp.py" ]
  args: {}
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but deployment-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). --- From what I see, I'd assume that the container has no user defined and is thus running under root. In its default setting, openshift will randomize the user id for each pod.

Comment: Do you have src and myapp.py in it - check the file structure in docker? Also I saw that usually is used instead of ENTRYPOINT and CMD, only CMD [“python”, “./main.py”]

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov The file structure is correct. The container runs fine if I run it manually. Moreover, I tried changing the command to "ls app" and I get the same error - `level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: \"ls app/\": stat ls app/: no such file or directory"`. Also, I tried removing entrypoint and just adding the contents in CMD like you said but still I get "no such file or dierctory" error.

Comment: The fact you tagged this with kubernetes but didn't show the PodSpec leads me to believe the `command:` in your PodSpec is wrong, not the `Dockerfile`; that goes double for your newly posted `ls app/` example

Comment: @mdaniel I have updated my question with the podspec. Please have a look.

Comment: You didn't include the PodSpec, you posted only _some_ of your helm template, without showing the `"myapp.command"` from `_helpers.tpl`; while I can appreciate that your helm template may be the ultimate origin of this bug, `k get pod -o yaml` would allow us to rule in or out whether this is actually a kubernetes problem. The fact that you posted your Dockerfile and then explicitly supersede it with `image: { command: []` means I was on the right track and I wonder how you expected **anyone** to guess that information using only your original question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do here is to remove the part of the Helm chart here that provides `command:`, and overrides the image's `ENTRYPOINT`.  The image already knows what command it's supposed to run (if oddly split across two Docker directives) and you don't need to specify it when you run the image.  Similarly, it'd be odd to reconfigure this at deploy time to run some other command without substantially rearchitecting the container setup.

```yaml
containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
    imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.imagePullPolicy }}
    # but you don't need to specify command: or make it configurable
```

If it's important to you to make this configurable, you're probably running into a syntax problem with the default Go serialization of lists out of templates.  If you run `helm template` over your chart, it'll probably print something like

```yaml
containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: gitlab-registry.cern.ch/batch-team/hepspec-query/hepspec-query:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: [python3 src/hepspecapp.py]
```

That is, `.Values.command` is a list, and it's parsed and stored internally as a list, and you're getting a default serialization that's not what's in the `values.yaml` file.  It turns out that *is* valid YAML, by coincidence, but now it's a list containing a single string that contains an embedded space.

Helm contains a lightly-documented `toYaml` function that can convert an arbitrary structure back to valid YAML.  This is indented starting at the first column so you need to make sure to appropriately `indent` the result.

```yaml
containers:
  - name: myapp
{{- if .Values.command }}
    command:
{{ .Values.command | toYaml | indent 6 }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.args }}
    args:
{{ .Values.args | toYaml | indent 6 }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Be careful, I think you made the same mistake OP did: `command: [python3, src/hepspecapp.py]`; separately, I've been trying to break my colleagues of the `{{ if` habit: `{{ with .Values.command }}command: {{ toYaml . | indent 6 }}` is the less copy-pasta version of that